# Eclipse Icon is availabe after its deletion

Tags: uninstall, delete

I deleted eclipse, but its icon not gone what to do?
[image]

As you can see when I search for "ec", I got eclipse as a suggestion thought without icon, but I don't want that suggestion either.

Comment: How did you remove eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

```sh
rm ~/.local/share/applications/eclipse.desktop
sudo rm  /usr/share/applications/eclipse.desktop
```

it looks like you followed [this article](https://linoxide.com/install-eclipse-on-ubuntu-20-04/)?

Comment: it didn't worked, but those files are deleted, i deleted .eclipse file, no change

Comment: Running `sudo rm  /usr/share/applications/eclipse.desktop` is bad idea. Such folders are controlled by APT.